# AMD Catalyst - auto brightness issue

Tags: windows-8, graphics-card, amd-radeon, amd-catalyst

I have a LG 22ea63v monitor and i recently bought (i was using my cpu's graphics card) a gigabyte 7790 graphics card. My OS is windows 8.

I've installed the latest version of amd catalyst.

The problem is that, when dark scenes displayed, my picture goes even darker and when bright scenes displayed, my picture goes brighter. This happens **constantly** and it's very annoying.

When i take off my graphics card and switch back to my cpu's, the problem goes away.

Here i've found the same problem, but no answer. http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/266649-33-disable-auto-brightness

Answer (score 1):

This is called Varibright. Everyone seems to hate it, but because a monitor's contrast ratio is measured by comparing the brightness of a white screen to that of a black screen, monitors with Varibright invariably score better than monitors without it. So that's what people buy.

The real solution is not to buy monitors or graphics cards with Varibright or anything remotely similar, but going by your question it is too late for that (as it was for me).

On my computer, Varibright started happening after I installed Catalyst (the program you mention installing) but it didn't go away after I uninstalled it (for shame, AMD). Catalyst had put its tentacles so deep into the system that I couldn't figure out what was left behind, so I had to use system restore to fix the problem.

If system restore doesn't work for you, maybe because the offending bit of software had been preinstalled on your computer, your best bet is to go for a clean install. But since that is a bit drastic, let me offer these two things to google for: PP_VariBrightFeatureEnable and atibtmon.exe. But don't get your hopes up. Your setup sounds pretty similar to mine and the first solution disabled my monitor brightness control completely and the second had no effect.

I hope you can get rid of it. If you do, don't ever come near Catalyst again.